# Force another submit before default submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to send form data to api after submit, but the forms have a action to another page at the same time, but i need do that without change html code, because this needs to get forms automatically and when submit get inputs values to send api before continue your default action, look

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="teste1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/anotherpage">
        <label for="myName">Send me your name:</label>
        <input id="myName" name="name" value="John"><br>
        <label for="myEmail">Send me your email:</label>
        <input id="myEmail" name="email" value="Exemplo@exemplo.com"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Me!">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

teste1.js

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {

function sendData() {

  const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const FD = new FormData( form );
  const data = {

    name: FD.get('name'),
    email: FD.get('email')

  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
  } );
  XHR.addEventListener( "error", function( event ) {
  } );
  XHR.open( "POST", "API_URL" );
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
  XHR.send(JSON.stringify(data));

}

const form = document.forms.item(0);
  form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    sendData();
    event.currentTarget.submit();

  } );
} );
```

this `sendData();` works perfecly without `event.currentTarget.submit();`, it doesn't work because that reflesh to action page when `event.currentTarget.submit();`, it's stopping the connection to send data.

i don't know how to solve this, i try putting setTimeOut to wait 2 seconds before back to action, but this `event.currentTarget.submit();` doesn't work in setTimeout function, can someone help me please, thanks.

Comment: `event.currentTarget.submit()` will trigger the same submit listener again. So - _remove_ it, before you try to submit the form again …?

Comment: if i remove `event.currentTarget.submit();` this `action="/anotherpage"`doesn't execute, i need return to action after ´sendData()´

Comment: I did not mean remove that, I meant remove the submit event handler. (_After_ it has fired for the first time.)

Comment: @CBroe, so you mean that one line should be added: `form.removeEventListener("submit");` ?  Should this line be added right before `event.currentTarget.submit();` ? Should the line `event.preventDefault();` be removed?

Comment: Yes; only `removeEventListener` does not work this way; you need the reference to the function object that you added as event listener in the first place. _“Should the line event.preventDefault(); be removed?”_ - no, you still want to handle the _first_ submit yourself via your script code, and not just let the browser submit the form normally at this point.

Comment: is there a way to use `XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
  } );` to return `event.currentTarget.submit();` or something than run default submit again?, because i think this XHR Event run when api return "success".